# Why I can not gather this object name and numbers 0,1,2,3?

Tags: javascript

```
var person = {name:"jack", lastName: "nikolson", year: 64};

function ope() {
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    person["name" + i] + "\n"
  }
}

document.write(ope());
```

I want to use bracket calling method in this object person, but it is undefined...why?
I want to write jack1 jack2 jack3 jack4 but it is undefined

Comment: You `document.write` nothing since your `ope` function returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `person` object obviously doesn't have keys `name0`, `name1`, `name2` and `name3`. And that code in the loop actually does nothing. Your function `ope` needs to return something in case you want to do some output with `document.write`.

Maybe something like (not entirely sure what you're trying to do):

```js
var person = {name:"jack", lastName: "nikolson", year: 64};

function ope(){
  var out = '';
  for(i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    out += person["name"] + i + "\n";
  }
  return out;
} 
document.write(ope());
```

Comment: can you remake this code without var out, and return value?

Answer (score 1):

`person["name"]` is "jack", however `person["name1"]`is undefined. What you want is `person["name"] + i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code below:

```
var person = {name:"jack", lastName: "nikolson", year: 64};

function ope() {
  var result = '';
  for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    result += person["name"] + (i+1) + "\n" //add 1 to i variable
  }

  return result;
}

document.write(ope()); //jack1 jack2 jack3 jack4
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a your function to have a return value.  As you have it, you aren't doing anything the values you iterate through.  Assign them to a string

Also you need to move 'i' outside of your [] because otherwise you are looking for properties name0, name1, name2... which do not exist

```js
    var person = {
      name: "jack",
      lastName: "nikolson",
      year: 64
    };

    function ope() {
      var str = '';
      for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        str += person["name"] + i + " ";
      }
      return str;
    }
    document.write(ope());
```